# multicolumn text wrapping in longtable

Tags: longtable

I need a table from the longtable or other package
I need columns Titles, Features and highlights and Dataset. Following code generates the wrapped table but I cannot resize the column with text wraps to make it look nicer. Please take a look into to attached image at the bottom of this.

Right now all the columns are of same size but wanted to resize the columns and wrap the text for instance  Features column needs to be bigger.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xltabular}

\begin{center}
        \begin{longtable}
        {@{}
        >{\raggedright}p{1.5in}
        p{6.5cm}
        >{\raggedleft}p{}@{1.5cm}
        >{\raggedright}p{0.5cm}
        p{3.5in}
        @{}}

        \caption{Previous Studies} \label{grid_mlmmh} \\

        \hline 

        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Studies(s)}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Features and Highlights}} & 
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Dataset}}\\ 

        \hline 
        \endfirsthead

        \multicolumn{3}{c}%

        {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
        \hline 
         \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Studies(s)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Features and Highlights}} & 
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Dataset}}\\ 
        \endhead

        \hline \multicolumn{3}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \hline
        \endfoot

        \hline \hline
        \endlastfoot
        \textbf{General Introduction}\\

        \cite{Baldominos2019}& Dataset 1998 & Comparative Study \\


        \cite{LeCunn1998} & Dataset & Multilayer Perceptron \\ \\
        LeCun, et. al. \cite{Y.LeCun1998}& 1998 & Introduction of Dataset \\

        \hline
        \textbf{Survey} \\

        \cite{Bianchini2006} Survey 
        \cite{Cai2018}, \cite{Goyal2018},  \cite{Cui2019}& comprehensive surveys on graph, network embeddings: (node clustering,  node recommendation, link prediction, graph classification, visualization, systematic taxonomization), graph reconstruction and support network inference,  survey of related studies &
        BlogCatalog, Flicker, Twitter, DBLP, Cora, Citeseer, ArXiv, Biological, etc\\

        \textbf{Recurrent Graph Neural Networks(RecGNNs)}\\

        \textbf{Studies}: \cite{Scarselli2009}, \cite{Gallicchio2010}, \cite{Li2016},\cite{Dai2018}&
        - Iterative information propagation from target node into neighbors 
        - Recursion and iteration, subgraph matching, the mutagenesis, ranking &
        MNIST, Facebook Entity Relaionships\\

        \textbf{Convolutional Graph Neural Netoworks(ConvGNNs)} \\

        - \textbf{Spectral-based Approaches (spectral graph theory)} \\
        \textbf{Studies}: \cite{Bruna2014}, \cite{Defferrard2016}, \cite{Kipf2017}, \cite{Li2018}, \cite{Z}&
        &
        - Spectral formulation, Strictly localized filters, low computational complexity, efficient pooling,
        - Features of Geometric Properties to low-dimensional grid structure (eg data of social networks, collaborative filtering)
        - general non-Euclidean domains (eg unstructured text data) 
        - Graph Estimation procedures &
        MNIST, 20NEWS, Citation Networks (eg PubMed, CiteSeer) \\

        - \textbf{Spatial-based Approaches}\\
        \textbf{Studies: } \cite{Micheli2009}, \cite{Atwood2016}, \cite{Niepert2016}, \cite{Hamilton2017}, \cite{Gao2018}, \cite{Tran2019}&
        \textbf{Features: }\\
        - cascade correlation, recursive neural networks, learning in strctured domains\\
        - graph diffusion, normalization of graph structure, \\
        \textbf{Example Dataset: } Quantitative structure-property
        relationship (QSPR)  of Alkanes, CORA and Pubmed, \\power grid system in the USA, email-enron \\
        \hline

        \textbf{Graph Autoencoders(GAEs)}\\
        \textbf{Studies: }\\
        \textbf{Features: }\\
        \textbf{Example Dataset: }\\
        \hline

        \textbf{Spatial-temporal Graph Neural Networks(STGNNs)} \\
        \hline




        \end{longtable}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages.

Comment: `>{\raggedleft}p{}@{1.5cm}` is not correct because the `p` type column needs a width as argument. Also, add `\arraybackslash` as in `\raggedleft\arraybackslash`. The same applies to `\raggedright` and `\centering`. And remove the `@{1.5cm}`.

Comment: Also, remove the `center` environment around the `longtable`. Longtables are horizontally centerd by default.

Comment: A `\\ `is missing after `\multicolumn{3}{r}{Continued on next page}`.

Comment: @leandriis also the `center` environment would not center longtable anyway as it is full width, `flushleft` or `flushright` environments are similar but they would not change the centred alignment of the table.

Comment: thank you all. I am new to latex community and learning it day by day. I wanted to have a table that flows to two or three pages, and has three columns, mid column has lots of text.

Comment: Please also add the documentclass you are using. To be honest, I don't understand the desired layout of the table. You mentioned 3 columns but used 5 in your code. Which column does "Comparative Study" , "Multilayer Perceptron "  and so on belong to? Are they supposed to be in the "Dataset" column? Probably a sketch of the desired output could help.

Comment: its `\documentclass{article}`

Comment: Since you just edited your question and added an image: Is this the output you currently get? This screenshot does not match the code in your question. How did you produce it?

Comment: No,  thats not what I get, I get words overlapping each other, ideally what I wanted is a similar table as in the image and I wanted to make the columns width more dynamic

Comment: Recurrent Graph Neural Networks(RecGNNs) for example I want in the one line, while there are three columns underneath it and above it. So essentially tables with multiple columns and multiple panels running across pages

Comment: @lpt: Something like : https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlRFx.png?

Comment: @leandriis  yes, thi is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you

Comment: and as @Zarko offered a solution below as well. that is also looks good. Thank you all you who is helping me charter previously uncharted path. You guys rock! Stay safe!

Answer (score 1):

I guessing, that you looking for tale like the following:

[image]

For it are to your MWE are added the following packages:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{microtype}
```

Complete MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, xltabular}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight%
                       \hsize=#1\hsize%                
                       \linewidth=\hsize}X}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                  label=\textbullet,
                  wide,
                  after={\end{minipage}},
                  before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}}
                  }
    \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{} L{0.6}
  >{\hsize=1.2\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X
                                      L{1.2} 
                                  @{}}
\caption{Previous Studies} 
\label{grid_mlmmh} \\
    \toprule
\thead{Studies(s)}  
    &   \thead{Features and Highlights}
        &   \thead{Dataset}                                         \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Previous Studies -- continued from previous page}        \\
\thead{Studies(s)}
    &   \thead{Features and Highlights}
        &   \thead{Dataset}                                         \\
    \midrule
\endhead
    \multicolumn{3}{r}{\small\itshape{Continued on next page}}      \\
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
% table body
\textbf{Survey}         &   &                                       \\
\cite{Bianchini2006}, \cite{Cai2018}, \cite{Goyal2018}, \cite{Cui2019}
    &   comprehensive surveys on graph, network embeddings: (node clustering,  node recommendation, link prediction, graph classification, visualization, systematic taxonomization), graph reconstruction and support network inference,  survey of related studies
        &   BlogCatalog, Flicker, Twitter, DBLP, Cora, 
            Citeseer, ArXiv, Biological, etc                        \\
    \addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{l}{%
    \thead{Recurrent Graph Neural Networks(RecGNNs)}}               \\
\textbf{Studies}:       &   &                                       \\
\cite{Scarselli2009}, \cite{Gallicchio2010}, \cite{Li2016}, \cite{Dai2018}
    &   \begin{itemize}
    \item   Iterative information propagation from target node into neighbors
    \item   Recursion and iteration, subgraph matching, the mutagenesis, ranking
        \end{itemize}
        &   MNIST, Facebook Entity Relaionships                     \\
    \addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{l}{%
    \thead{Convolutional Graph Neural Netoworks(ConvGNNs)}}         \\
    \addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{l}{%
    \thead{Spectral-based Approaches (spectral graph theory)}}      \\
\textbf{Studies}:       &   &                                       \\
\cite{Bruna2014}, \cite{Defferrard2016}, \cite{Kipf2017}, \cite{Li2018}, \cite{Z}
    & \begin{itemize}
    \item   Spectral formulation, Strictly localized filters, low computational complexity, efficient pooling,
    \item   Features of Geometric Properties to low-dimensional grid structure (eg data of social networks, collaborative filtering)
    \item   general non-Euclidean domains (eg unstructured text data)
    \item   Graph Estimation procedures
            \end{itemize}
        &   MNIST, 20NEWS, Citation Networks (eg PubMed, CiteSeer) \\
    \end{xltabular}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: for some reason this code did not compile in overleaf

Comment: @lpt, oh Overleaf .... it seems that it hasn't installed `xltabular` package ... you need ask Ovewrleaf maintainers for help. I don't use them, so I can't help you in this matter.

Comment: Ah okay, I will tag Overleaf if they can advise